# php how to do a loop to calculate score for a quiz website

Tags: php

i am creating a quiz website using php where there are 4 questions for users to answer. there is a home page before this for them to choose either math or lit that they wish to do.

after selecting the subject, user need to answer the question and submit their answer, then the php code will calculate their score and count the number of correct/wrong answers.

<ArrayquesAns.php> is the array of questions and answers
[it looks something like this, there are 2 array in this php, 1 is math question and another 1 is lit question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4prt.png)

and here is the main code where it will generate questions from the question pool randomly. i also tried to put in the code to calculate score

```
<html>

    <body>

        <?php
        require_once 'ArrayQuesAns.php'; //retrieve array of ques

        $_SESSION["subject"] = $_GET['subject']; //suppose to put value when session starts
        $_SESSION["name"] = $_GET['name'];

        $subject = $_SESSION["subject"];
        $name = $_SESSION["name"];

        $url = "displayScore.php?name=" . $name . "&subject=" . $subject . "&";


        if ($subject == "mathematics") { //math session
            $mathQues_key = array_rand($Mathques, 4); //Pick 4 random rows in array

            $MathquesRand = array(); //New array to contain the 4 random rows

            $i = 0;
            foreach ($mathQues_key as $key) {
                $MathquesRand[$i] = $Mathques[$key];
                $i++;
            }
            ?>  
            
            <form action="<?= $url ?>" method="get"> 


                <h1> Section : <?= $subject ?> </h1>
                <p>Hello <?= $name ?>! You may start your quiz !<p>
                <hr>

                <?php foreach ($MathquesRand as $qtsno => $value) { ?>
                    <?php echo $value["ques"] . " = \t"; ?> <!--Display Question -->

                    <input type="text" name="userans" value="<?php echo isset($_GET["userans"]) ? $_GET["userans"] : ''; ?>">
                    <br>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php
                foreach ($MathquesRand as $qtsno => $value) {

                    array_key_exists($userans = $_GET["userans"]);
                    $score = 0;
                    $overall = 0;
                    $correct = 0;
                    $wrong = 0;

                    if ($userans == $value["ans"]) {
                        $correct += 1;
                    } else {
                        $wrong += 1;
                    }
                    $score = ($correct * 5) - ($wrong * 3);


                    "\n\n\n";
                    echo $value["ans"];
                    echo $correct;
                    echo $wrong;
                    echo $score;
                }
                ?>

                <br>
                <button type="submit">SUBMIT ATTEMPT</button>
            </form>
    <?php
} else { //Lit Section
    $LitQues_key = array_rand($Litques, 4);

    $LitquesRand = array();

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($LitQues_key as $key) {
        $LitquesRand[$i] = $Litques[$key];
        $i++;
    }
    ?>  

            
            <form action="<?= $url ?>" method="get">

                <h1> Section : <?= $subject ?></h1>
                <p>Hello <?= $name ?> ! You may start your quiz !<p>
                <hr>

    <?php foreach ($LitquesRand as $qtsno => $value) {
        echo $value["ques"], " = \t";
        ?> <!--Display Question -->

                    <input type="text" name="userans" value="<?php echo isset($_GET["userans"]) ? $_GET["userans"] : ''; ?>">
                    <br>
                <?php } ?>
                    
                    <?php
                foreach ($MathquesRand as $qtsno => $value) {

                    array_key_exists($userans = $_GET["userans"]);
                    $score = 0;
                    $overall = 0;
                    $correct = 0;
                    $wrong = 0;

                    if ($userans == $value["ans"]) {
                        $correct += 1;
                    } else {
                        $wrong += 1;
                    }
                    $score = ($correct * 5) - ($wrong * 3);


                    "\n\n\n";
                    echo $value["ans"];
                    echo $correct;
                    echo $wrong;
                    echo $score;
                }
                ?>
                    
                <br>
                <button type="submit">SUBMIT ATTEMPT</button>
            </form>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

        <!--Exit-->
        <a href="exit.php"><button type="button">EXIT</button></a>
    </body>

</html>
```

i think this part is where it has issue

```
               foreach ($MathquesRand as $qtsno => $value) {

                   array_key_exists($userans = $_GET["userans"]);
                   $score = 0;
                   $overall = 0;
                   $correct = 0;
                   $wrong = 0;

                   if ($userans == $value["ans"]) {
                       $correct += 1;
                   } else {
                       $wrong += 1;
                   }
                   $score = ($correct * 5) - ($wrong * 3);


                   "\n\n\n";
                   echo $value["ans"];
                   echo $correct;
                   echo $wrong;
                   echo $score;
               }
```

the code should match user input answer with array question/answer to see if the answer is correct. every correct question will *5 and every wrong answer will *3 (the formula is in the code).

i am not sure if i place the code in the wrong bracket hence its not working or there is some logic error or should i run the code to find the score in a separate php?

**after user submit their answer, it will redirect to another page that display their score and number of correct/wrong answers like this**
[score display html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB5FK.png)

Comment: What is your purpose in the line `array_key_exists($userans = $_GET["userans"]);` ?

Comment: On the other hand, Since you have random questions picking-up to happen at the start of the page,  I think the questions displayed in the 1st page (displaying the random questions for students to answer) will not be the same AFTER he/she submits the result (showing the answers). In that case how can the system accurately calculate the scores ??

Comment: @KenLee theres always an error saying undefined array key when i try to call the value of userans

Comment: @KenLee i think probably the calculation of scores must be within the same loop as generating the question? so that it does not regenerate a new set of questions?

Comment: Definitively. There is no point to separate them into two loops. But you need to fix the random question extraction problem on each page reload too .

Comment: I have spared some time to write a working version of your MC test (mathematics only). Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original version of the MC test, please find below a working version:

To make it simple, I have removed the "Name" and "Subject" of the form to demonstrate the necessary coding.

1. You can still use the array_rand to draw 4 random questions
2. However, after the questions are displayed to the student (and student can input the answer) and clicked "Submit Attempt", the page will remember the random questions drawn - I have used a trick :- to store the questions randomly drawn into a hidden input box
3. The system will compare the student's submitted answer with that of the correct answer and determine whether it is correct or wrong, and show the score
4. To fix the "undefined array" errors you encountered, I applied the isset function on places relating to the $_GET variables. (Actually these are warnings, not errors, but it is for sure a good practice to use isset)

```
<?php
//require_once 'ArrayQuesAns.php'; //retrieve array of ques

$Mathques=array(
1=> array('no'=>1, 'ques'=>"3+1", 'ans'=>"4"),
2=> array('no'=>2, 'ques'=>"3+3", 'ans'=>"6"),
3=> array('no'=>3, 'ques'=>"3+4", 'ans'=>"7"),
4=> array('no'=>4, 'ques'=>"3+5", 'ans'=>"8"),
5=> array('no'=>5, 'ques'=>"3+6", 'ans'=>"9"),
6=> array('no'=>6, 'ques'=>"3+7", 'ans'=>"10"),
7=> array('no'=>7, 'ques'=>"3+8", 'ans'=>"11"),
8=> array('no'=>8, 'ques'=>"3+9", 'ans'=>"12"),
9=> array('no'=>9, 'ques'=>"3+10", 'ans'=>"13"),
10=> array('no'=>10, 'ques'=>"3+11", 'ans'=>"14")
);


if (! isset($_GET["draw"])) {
$mathQues_key = array_rand($Mathques, 4); //Pick 4 random rows in array
}

$MathquesRand = array(); //New array to contain the 4 random rows

if (! isset($_GET["draw"])  ) {

$i = 0;
foreach ($mathQues_key as $key) {
$MathquesRand[$i] = $Mathques[$key];
$i++;
}

}


?>  
<?php

if (isset($_GET["draw"]) && $_GET["draw"] !="") {
   $pieces = explode(",", $_GET["draw"]);
   $index=0;
   while ($index < count($pieces)) {
     if ($pieces[$index]!=""){
      $MathquesRand[] = $Mathques[$pieces[$index]];
     }
    $index++;
   }
}
?>

<form action="" method="get"> 

<?php
$correct=0;
$wrong=0;
?>
<h1> Section : Mathematics </h1>
<p>Hello ! You may start your quiz !<p>
<hr>

<?php
$pool="";
$ii=1;
 foreach ($MathquesRand as $qtsno => $value) { 
$pool.= $value["no"]. ",";

 ?>

<?php echo $value["ques"] . " = \t"; ?> <!--Display Question -->
<input type="text" name="userans<?php echo $ii; ?>" 

<?php if (isset($_GET["userans".$ii])) 
{ 
    echo " value='" .$_GET["userans".$ii] . "'>" ; 
} else { echo ">" ; } 
?>



<?php if (isset($_GET["userans".$ii]) && $_GET["userans".$ii]==$value["ans"]) {
$correct++;
} else {
$wrong++;
}
?>

<br>
<?php 
$ii++;
} 
?>

<input name=draw type=hidden value="<?php echo $pool; ?>">
<br>
<button type="submit">SUBMIT ATTEMPT</button>
</form>

<?php
 $score = ($correct * 5) - ($wrong * 3);
 ?>
 
<?php if (isset($_GET["draw"])) { ?>

<font color=red>Result:</font>
<br>Correct:<?php echo $correct;?>
<br>Wrong:<?php echo $wrong;?>
<br>Score:<?php echo $score;?>
<?php } ?>
```

To share my experience (I have coded such Multiple Choice Q & A functions many times) , **in future** if you want to do similar thing, please consider using

1. database to store the drawn questions ;
2. use ajax to compare the input data with the correct data stored in the db, instead of using form submission

Comment: thank you, i roughly get the concept of how you are doing it. thanks alot